# Devise sending forgot password instructions to any email id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am looking for a customization in devise where if we click on forgot password it should send the mail to any e-mail id . Something like it happens in  Gmail, irrespective of the email id exists or not.

**Screen 1**
[image]

**Screen 2**
[image]

**Currently what i have is** this in which it tries to validate with the valid users in the system.

[image]

The [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), [recoverable module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb) takes care of this

```
       def send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})
          recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(reset_password_keys, attributes,   :not_found)
          recoverable.send_reset_password_instructions if recoverable.persisted?
          recoverable
        end
```

How can i remove this validation and have email sent to any Email id?

Comment: Devise controls presence of users. What is your devise version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a Devise configuration called `paranoid` that, when set to true, would change the message in a way to avoid e-mail enumeration. Just set `config.paranoid = true` in your Devise configuration.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to extend/override Devise's passwords controller. To do this, create a controller (let's call it passwords) that inherits from Devise's passwords controller, like this:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
```

Then edit your routes file so this change takes effect:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => 'passwords' }
```

Now, you'll want to override the [`create` action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L12). There are several ways you could do this but since I'm not sure of what you want to do, I'll show you 2 things you could do:

1. You only want to prevent the "Email not found" error so that people can't find which emails exist or not in your database:

   ```
   def create
     self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

     respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
   end
   ```
2. You really want to send emails to any entered email:

   ```
   def create
     self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

     unless successfully_sent?(resource)
       Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(resource).deliver
     end

     respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
   end
   ```

Now, the problem with this last solution is that you are sending an email to a user that doesn't exist... And so when the user comes back, he won't be able to enter his new password since his user account can't be found. But if you really want to do this, hopefully I set you on the right track.